# Trying to create a dataframe from another dataframe with certain restrictions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a VAR model in Python (where it is not allowed to use pre-made functions such as VAR within statsmodel).

For this I need the matrix of the dependent variables.
I have a data set of 3 government bonds, all with different maturities. 
The data is imported and treated as follows

```
# importing file
df = pd.read_csv("C://Users/raymond/Desktop/Econometrie3/us_tbills_8019.csv")

# dropping years > 1999
df = df.iloc[:240]

# calculating log differences
Dates = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
mData = df[['GS10','GS5','GS1']]
mData.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(Dates)
AllData = mData
logdif = np.log(mData).diff().shift(1).dropna()
```

To create the matrix Y, which is the matrix of dependent variables, I want to take values of *logdif* with range i = 1:K and j = P+1:T-1

I tried the following to create my matrix:

```
# variables
K = 3
T = df.shape[0]
P = 4

# matrix of Dependent Variable
Y = logdif
def functionY():
    for i in range(1, 3, 1):
        for j in range(P+1, T-1, 1):
            Y[i][j-1] = logdif[i][j]
        return Y
```

I have tried other ways to find the matrix as well, with none working.
Any tips for creating my matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot understand all of your code (so there may be other problems), but I notice that you're assigning your dataframe `logdif` to a second variable `Y` and then writing values to `Y`. You should be aware that this modifies `logdif`, as it is only assigned by reference. (This doesn't look like what you want, since you're reading from `logdif` at the same time.)

Use `Y = logdif.copy()` to avoid that.

Edit: Also, `range(1,3,1)` is identical to `range(1,3)`.

Edit: Also, you mention that you are trying to create a *matrix*; the variable you're using right now is still a DataFrame (np.log preserves the type of the argument here). You can use `Y = np.matrix(logdif)` to change this.

Comment: Using copy indeed did what i wanted to do.
Thank you for your answer